# Alfresco Custom Role

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Has anyone worked on Alfresco custom roles. Alfresco out of box provides only 4 roles on the site.
So the minimum Alfresco provides is Consumer role while I have requirement where customer can search for the document and not open to see the metadata of the document. Is it possible to customize in this way.

Comment: What can he do with the document he finds, nothing? If he's not allowed to see the metadata, what metadata will be displayed in search results?

Comment: User can see the metadata associated with document but not the actual content of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is not so much creating a new role, but rather that Alfresco expects at least the rights of the role of consumer. Otherwise Alfresco (Share) will not work. So my answer is: implementing a custom alfresco role is not the solution for your requirement.

We have created an (commerical) AddOn "ecm4u View Only", which limits the role of the consumer to reading metadata only and to a certain preview rendition (which we create via our implementation), if the aspect "ViewOnly" is attached. In this way it is possible that users can find documents via all protocols, but cannot open them (not even via CIFS / DAV / CMIS) except see a special prepared preview rendition. In order to be able to open the content, at least write permissions are required as work around for these documents having the "ViewOnly" aspect.

Comment: U mean it will work on any wrapper around ACS but not on Alfresco Share ....

Comment: more or less: yes. If you implement your own Alfresco Client you may implement any role you like but as long as you use Alfresco's UI you need to handle your role requirement for the existing role "Consumer" under the hood behaving different for your restricted docs.